# Selecting a data frame within a time frame

Tags: python, dataframe, google-colaboratory

I'm practicing in colab and i have to select a data frame within a time period. The code in the picture below returns an empty data frame

[What I am trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cpNk.png)

What is weird that for a different date like this it brings results.

```
dfPeriod = dfv[(dfv['date'] >= '2021-01-20') & (dfv['date'] <= '2021-02-03')]
```

I dont know what I did wrong, it just looks like it works in one place and then it doesn't.

[Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eOQrWlFaqKHGHss5j_5hIqD3Ug0FKZmH?usp=sharing)

Comment: It would be great if you could post the link to the Colab as opposed to the screenshot

Comment: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1eOQrWlFaqKHGHss5j_5hIqD3Ug0FKZmH?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have trailing or leading whitespace in your data. You can clean your `country` column using `dfv['country'] = dfv['country'].str.strip()`

Or use `str.contains`:

```
countries = ['United Kingdom', 'Romania', 'Bulgaria', 'Brazil', 'United Arab Emirates']
dfFilter = dfPeriod[dfPeriod['country'].str.contains('|'.join(countries), case=False)]
```

Comment: I tried that, its not that. I dont know what is going on with the dates